# Database of all Coca Cola (and its franchises) bottling plants locations worldwide

Tags: data-request, economics, industry

For economics-related research I'm looking to map all the Coca Cola bottling plants worldwide. Where can I find such a list?

Answer (score 4):

The data is not apparently available as a downloadable dataset, but there are some documents and visualizations available.

- A great [visualization](https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/viewer?oe=UTF8&vpsrc=0&t=h&ie=UTF8&msa=0&mid=zIS6n3st1NKE.kYJ13h_kyMOI) of all the Coca Cola facilities (and [an associated KML file](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=ujLcCT8Y) -- thanks @philshem)
- Coca-Cola's [description](http://www.coca-colacompany.com/our-company/the-coca-cola-system#TCCC) of the facilities in the network
- Overall performance of the facilities in the annual [Sustainability Report](http://www.coca-colacompany.com/our-company/the-coca-cola-system#TCCC)
- Overview of [global facilities](http://www.coca-colacompany.com/annual-review/2013/img/TCCC_2013_Annual_Review.pdf)

Comment: From @Jeanne's Google Maps link you can click the share button and then download a KML file (XML-like)  - http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=ujLcCT8Y